# Export of script results to Excel not working

Tags: powershell-extensions

When I get a ListView with script results and want to export the results to Excel etc., nothing happens when I click on the buttons.
I do however get an error in the developer tools console:

> Failed to call scGetFrameValue in IFrame tag. This typically happens due to a Permission Denied exception in IE9 caused by an intricate issue with Popup and ShowModalDialog calls. Blocked a frame with origin "http://whatever.local" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

This is in the newest version of both Chrome and Firefox. I am using SPE 4.7.2 and Sitecore 8.2 update 5

Did anyone experience this problem before? When googling it, I can find some issues with Sitecore Experience Editor and jQuery noConflict, but I don't have that issue.

Comment: Have you upgraded the SPE recently? If so, try cleaning your browser cache.

Comment: I get lgoged out everytime I click on excel
I have the same error on console but i know it's a fake any more info you can give me on what you did on the ignoring part, pretty please?

Answer (score 5):

See this conversation here on github as @WulfgarDK is saying above - https://github.com/SitecorePowerShell/Console/issues/912

But this was not the reason in our case.

We had the same issue and solution was to enable `Spe.IdentityServer.config` at `\inetpub\wwwroot\website\App_Config\Include\Spe`.

OOTB this file comes with Sitecore Powershell module as disabled. Just need to remove `.disabled` from the config name.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I finally figured this out by looking at closed issues on the GitHub page, where someone had a similar issue, and it was similar to mine.

We have a custom `ItemNotFoundResolver` pipeline, and needed to add `/-/script` to the URLs to ignore.