# Export buttons in Show-ListView is not working

Tags: powershell-extensions, powershell

I know there is a similar [question](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/10361/export-of-of-script-results-to-excel-not-working) before but it has different error than mine. In my `ListView` result, when I try to click any of the export buttons, nothing happens. Upon checking the SPE logs, this is what I got:

```
   ManagedPoolThread #4 03:41:36 ERROR 'InsufficientSecurityRights' (Category: PermissionDenied) error encountered on object.
Exception: System.FormatException 
Message: Handle Download Service is disabled or user is not authorized.
```

I checked my `Cognified.PowerShell.config`, and `<handleDownload>` is already enabled and allowed all permissions. I wonder if any of you encountered the same issue?

Comment: Seems like a strange combination of messages. I would not expect to see a FormatException along with the Handle error. Did something recently change in your instance like upgrade packages?

Comment: Actually, the export button is working fine in my Sitecore local instance. This issue is currently found in Content Management instance. Upon checking Cognified.PowerShell.config, their handleDownload service is the same. My username role is admin, but the issue is still existing. @MichaelWest

Comment: Can you provide details about the environment and how it's different than your local setup?

Comment: @MichaelWest The environment I'm using is hosted on amazon ec2 instances has dedicated cd, cm, cloning, and publishing servers, and db servers. The enterprise sign on I use is federation STS(ADFS). It also have dedicated STS servers. 

My local instance is using Sitecore 8.2, I installed the PowerShell Version 5.

Comment: I am getting error in SpeShared.js on click of List-View document download.

Answer (score 1):

Explicitly adding the user's name in the Cognified.Powershell.config solves the issue.